# SyncFusion Print PDF from Instanced Control?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2015, syncfusion

I've recently downloaded the free SyncFusion tools for WinForm. My main interest was the PDF stuff since there isn't much that will print a PDF without using an external program.

When I use a PDFViewerControl on the form I can load the PDF and silently print it without issue.

```
    PdfViewerControl1.Load("D:\test.pdf")
    PdfViewerControl1.Print(False)
```

However when I instance the control it dosne't work.

```
    Dim PDFControl As Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer.PdfViewerControl
    PDFControl.Load("D:\test.pdf")
    PDFControl.Print(True)
```

It acts like it worked, no error etc. But it doesn't actually do anything. I'm wondering if I'm just using it the wrong way. Any ideas?

Edit:

Something weird, if I add a print control to the code it print silently.

```
    Dim PDFControl As New Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer.PdfViewerControl()
    PDFControl.Load("D:\test.pdf")

    Dim dialog As New PrintDialog()
    dialog.AllowPrintToFile = True
    dialog.Document = PDFControl.PrintDocument
    dialog.Document.Print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for using Syncfusion products. This issue will be fixed in our next release 'Essential Studio 2017 Volume 1' which will be available in mid February, 2017.

Comment: Will this require VS 2017?

Comment: No it won't require VS 2017